# ORACLE SQL Query About Delete

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like the one below.

```sql
SELECT k.A, k.B, AVG(POINT)
FROM   Table1 k
       JOIN Table2 l ON (k.MID=l.MID)
GROUP BY (k.A, k.B) HAVING YEAR BETWEEN 1999 AND 2021;
```

The result of this query is like the table below.

| A | B | AVG(POINT) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | 2021 | 4 |
| D | 1999 | 3 |

I want to write the query that deletes those average score is less than 4.For this, I wrote the following query but it failed. How can I write the query?

```sql
SELECT k.A, k.B, AVG(POINT)
FROM   Table1 k
       JOIN Table2 l ON (k.MID=l.MID)
GROUP BY (k.A, k.B)
HAVING YEAR BETWEEN 1999 AND 2021 (AND HAVING AVG(POINT)<4);
```

Comment: Please share sample data and table structure.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statements for your tables; the DML (`INSERT`) statements for your sample data; an explanation (English, not code) of the goal you are trying to achieve and the logic you want to use; your expected output; what the issues are with your current query that you want to solve. At the moment we don't know what inputs you have nor do we have a complete understanding of the problem so please help us to help you by giving us all the information necessary to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the [A] column is a unique identifier you could do a subquery to delete the data below 4, like this:

```
DELETE Table1 WHERE A IN (SELECT T.A FROM (SELECT k.A, k.B, AVG(POINT)
FROM Table1 k JOIN
     Table2 l
     ON k.MID = l.MID                                                           
GROUP BY k.A, k.B
WHERE YEAR BETWEEN 1999 AND 2021
HAVING AVG(POINT) < 4)T)
```

If A is not unique, you might delete rows where the `POINT` value is bigger than for just because the average of all `[A]` is less than for

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax you want is:

```
SELECT k.A, k.B, AVG(POINT)
FROM Table1 k JOIN
     Table2 l
     ON k.MID = l.MID                                                           
GROUP BY k.A, k.B
WHERE YEAR BETWEEN 1999 AND 2021
HAVING AVG(POINT) < 4;
```

Note that `YEAR` is not being aggregated.  It looks like it should be filtered *before* the aggregation (i.e. using `WHERE`) rather than `HAVING`.

Comment: How can I delete values whose average is less than 4 points?

Comment: @MehmetAliKarabulut please check my answer to know how to delete the values

Comment: @MehmetAliKarabulut The average is an aggregation of multiple rows so you need to clarify what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to delete input rows so that the average is brought above 4 (you might have input rows below 4 but the remaining average could be above 4)? Do you want all input rows below 4 deleted (then why do you need to find the average)? Do you just want to not show the rows where the average is below 4 (in that case why do you need to delete rows rather than having a filter condition)? Do you want to delete all input rows where the average is below 4?